# Data not entering into DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, import

I have imported Contact Object field from Sales Cloud via Import Activity into the Marketing Cloud. While trying to import contact Email field (Standard Contact email field) it is displayed as Text. I changed it to type Email. On changing the type it defaults to length 100.

[image: Import Activity Data Extension]

Further, I want to populate this Contact Email field into other data extension via Query activity. When i try to create a target data extension and add a field Email with type equal to Email it defaults to 255.

[image: Target Data Extension for Query Activity]

As there is a mismatch between the source data extension field length `[Email: length 100]` and target data extension field length `[Email: length 254]`, my query fails to insert email field into the target data extension. Any solution to  overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I typically import SF Reports into staging Data Extension and then use a Staging-to-Master Query Activity to handle data transformations.  In most cases, I just accept the default field precisions in the Import Activity.

Something like this will save you a lot of trouble:

```
select
 case 
   when len(s.email) > 100 then left(s.email,100) 
   else s.email 
 end as email
 , s.SubscriptionDueDate
from StagingDataExtension s
/* target MasterDataExtension */
/* action: update */
```

Comment: Is there a way to know whether the query is still in process or terminated? This is important because i am unable interpret that whether my query failed to return any output or it is still in process and fetching the results

Comment: You can see when it completes (or fails) if you run it from an Automation or Program.